# Find Day in The shell script

Tags: shell

How can I find the day & Location from the following output (Sample 1 & 2) and store in a file or variable using Shell script. The location are fixed.

```
Address can have the following location and days.

Location to choose from:
ABC St, Main St, Ridge Pike

Days to choose from:
Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
```

```
Output Sample - 1
***********
Order-101
Main St
Tuesday
************
```

```
Output Sample - 2
***********
Order-110
Ridge Pike
Friday
************
```

Comment: how do you relate the location and day ?

Answer (score 0):

We will call your program `foo`

```sh
$ IFS=$'\n' read -d! _ location day < <(foo)

$ echo $location
Main St

$ echo $day
Tuesday
```